# Boost a HV power supply from +1250 V to +1500 V

Tags: rf, high-voltage

I'm designing a base for a photomultiplier tube using a recycled HV power supply. The power supply is an [EMCO C12](http://www.emcohighvoltage.com/datasheets/cseries.pdf). The base has a 14 pin socket (to connect to the PMT), the EMCO C12, a DAC to program the EMCO C12, a 5 pin ZH connector (DAC), a 2 pin PH connector (DC in), and a BNC connector (Signal). Below is a schematic.

[image: Schematic]

My problem is that the gain of the PMT is simply not enough at the max voltage of the EMCO C12. If I could boost the voltage up just 250V then I could increase the gain almost 4 fold.

It's very important that the method used to boost the voltage maintains a very stable voltage output and be able to output . Also, it needs to introduce as little noise as possible to the output signal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get hold of a properly isolated 1:1 AC power transformer. Rectify and smooth the output (~330V DC). Put the rectified output in series with the HV power supply output. Job done.

This does rely on proper isolation between primary and secondary and if in doubt wind your own.

An alternative might be to buy some dc-to-dc converters that are properly isolating and float the outputs up.

If you are worried about floating the above outputs up you could float the actual HV output up by 250V DC maybe. It looks like you could put a dc-to-dc converter on the LV side of the device so it then becomes an isolated output. Then, raise HV ground to 250 VDC.

Alternatively just buy the next model up - the C15 model - it does 1.5 kV.